# SQL query for matching multiple values with wildcard

Tags: sql

I have a table in SQL as follow.

```
User            Location     group
Melissa Pows    Las Vegas    C Level 1
Melissa Pows    Las Vegas    Lasvegas Level 2
Kelley Mendez   Santa Clara  C Level 2
Kelley Mendez   Santa Clara  SantaClara level 3
Jason Words     Las Vegas    Lasvegas Level 2
Jason Words     Las Vegas    C Level 2
Chris Taylor    Las Vegas    LasVegas Level 4
Chris Taylor    Las Vegas    C Level 4
```

I want to return multiple value for user that have contains "C Level" and "LasVegas level" in group. when I use below, I don't have anything in return.

```
Select [user]  
    ,[location]
    ,[group]
From tablename
where location  = 'Las Vegas' and group like 'c level%' and group like 'Lasvegas level%'
```

Comment: `GROUP` is a reserved word in SQL. Avoid using it as an object identifier. If you do you'll need to quote it.

Answer (score 1):

The PATINDEX function return an integer > 0 if the pattern you want to isolate is found in the string. Add multiple PATINDEXs functions together in a WHERE clause and if their summation > 0 then at least one of the patterns has been found. In this example I am trying to exclude rows where an unwanted pattern exists in the STREET1 column

```
where PATINDEX('General Deli%', STREET1) 
+ PATINDEX('pobox %', STREET1) 
+ PATINDEX('%homeless%', STREET1) 
+ PATINDEX('% box %', STREET1) 
+ PATINDEX('University Tower%', STREET1) = 0
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql

Answer (score 0):

Your sample data is hard to read. If both wildcards work for themselves, use `or`:

```
where location = 'Las Vegas' and ( group like 'c level%' or group like 'Lasvegas level%' )
```

Comment: sorry, I wasn't clear. I want return value to give me the user name when they are part of any of C Level and Las Vegas Level.

Comment: Well. Yes. Add “select user from tabele” in front and go ahead

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
where location = 'Las Vegas' and upper(group) like '%LEVEL%'
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this:

```
SELECT [user] 
FROM TableName
WHERE [Location] = 'Las Vegas' AND ([group] LIKE 'C Level%' OR [group] LIKE 'Lasvegas Level%')
```

You're not getting any result because of your "AND" condition it's looking for a location with Las vegas that has a group with value of both C level and Last vegas level.

Note:
 I used brackets for the table columns to let sql know that it is a column example for the comment on your question "group" is a reserved word for sql.. if you place brackets sql will consider it as a column of a table.

Comment: sorry, I wasn't clear. I'm looking for the user that has C Level and Las Vegas Level.

Comment: updated the answer.. just change the "TableName" with what ever the name of your table is